# Json object access in Node server

Tags: json, node.js

I am new to Node server. In my program I fetched some data from data base as

```
connection.query("SELECT * from login where username='" + uname + "' and password='" + pwd + "' ", [uname, pwd], function (err, rows)
    {
        var employees = (JSON.stringify(rows));
        console.log("Inside server "+employees  )
    });
```

Now in console i got some thing like

```
[{"user_id":7,"username":"vb","password":"vbv"}]
```

Now my Question is how i could get the value `username` from `employees`. I have tried few things like
`employees[0]["username"]`  OR `employees.username` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(rows)` only allow you to pretty print the data.

To access it you were right with `employees[0]["username"]`

```
connection.query("SELECT * from login where username='" + uname + "' and password='" + pwd + "' ", [uname, pwd], function (err, employees)
    {
        console.log("Inside server " + JSON.stringify(employees));
        console.log('Employee 1: ' + employees[0]["username"]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you stringify it, it becomes string so you can't access like that. Just use it as is.